# Как использовать массив?

Tags: массивы, yii

В yii вывожу из БД данные таким образом:

```
$record=User::model()->findByAttributes(array('login'=>$this->username));
```

Если сделать:

```
echo '<pre>';print_r($record);echo '</pre>';
```

То на экран выводит:

```
[_attributes:CActiveRecord:private] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [login] => Myname
            [passwd] => 123456
            [created] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
        )
```

Как использовать этот массив? (мне нужно `id` присвоит к `$a`).

P.S. Как я пробовал лучше не стоит вам показать:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$record у вас является объектом и вы просто обращаетесь к его свойствам:

```
$a = $record->id;
echo $a;
```

Comment: пробовал не сработал, дает ошибку

Comment: сработал))) А я так пробовал: 
echo $record->id;
так не канает да?

Comment: Почему? Тоже должно.

Comment: Вообще-то ни так ни так не должно. Либо я неправильно понимаю ООП в PHP...
Все члены private - доступны только в классе. Следовательно вы не можете просто взять и получить значение. Для получения нужно написать метод GetId(), а для присвоения SetId(). Либо сделать члены класса public. По крайней мере так в С++.

Answer (score 2):

Так члены закрытые ведь? Напишите метод `SetId($_id)` и передайте Ваше `$a`